# How to find out to which polygon each points belongs to?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have searched for an answer to this, but couldn't find anything useful. I have got a shapefile consisting of a number of polygons, and another shapefile with a number of points.

I want to add a column in the points shapefile. For each point, I want the column to contain the name of the polygon that surrounds it.

In simple terms, I just want to find out to which polygon each points belongs to. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS, you find Join attributes by location and Add polygon attributes to points which both do what you want.

I just published a [comparison of the two tools](http://anitagraser.com/2013/10/02/add-polygon-attributes-to-points-vs-join-attributes-by-location/).